# How can we do sentiment analysis of remote stream in an agora app?

Tags: video, sentiment-analysis, agora.io

We would like to know how we can do sentiment analysis of remote video stream. We are using the agora [basic video call/ one to one video](https://github.com/AgoraIO/Basic-Video-Call/tree/master/One-to-One-Video/Agora-Web-Tutorial-1to1) as the starting point.

We searched extensively for the solution but we did not get what we are looking for.

`<label>Sentiment</label>`

The goal is to do sentiment analysis of the remote stream periodically and update the label.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the technology to do this exists. Certainly not in any off-the-shelf form.

Performing sentiment analysis on *text* is nontrivial, and involves a lot of algorithmic guesswork. Performing sentiment analysis on an amorphous format like video is unlikely to be possible in any kind of general, useful fashion.